# can't access NAS after 16.04 LTS upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I have a WD My Cloud NAS which I've been using for several years through Nautilus using a location bookmark (smb://000.000.0.000, not all zeros of course but the ip of the device). I have smbclient installed (but not Samba itself) and all was well until the 16.04 LTS upgrade.

Now, I cannot connect to the NAS at all - no error messages, just no connection.

I originally assumed this was due to a Samba bug (and on Launchpad there are a few) but now I'm not so sure because I can't connect using Gigolo either (which uses GVFS for network connections, an entirely different method than Samba).

So far I've reinstalled smbclient, gigolo, gvfs-fuse, restarted the computer and recreated my Nautilus bookmark (several times) all with no good result.

I don't have a great deal of Linux experience and am hoping someone here can help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1409032

provides the info re: this problem and post #29 has a workaround that solved it for me.